# Typescript Error: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-dnd'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, react-dnd

I am currently getting this error when importing `react-dnd`:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-dnd'. 'node_modules/react-dnd/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/react-dnd` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-dnd';
```

Doesn't `react-dnd` provide type definitions? Is there anything extra I have to do to get access to the types?

I am using typescript in strict mode. My app was scaffolded with create-react-app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-dnd` does indeed ship with type definitions as you can see here in [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/browse/react-dnd@11.1.3/lib/index.d.ts). You shouldn't need to do anything to access these types. Perhaps you are using an older version of react-dnd that does not have the types included?

Comment: Thank you, I was on version 2.6 instead of 11.1! I cloned a really old example from github...